# Combine Label Text With Image

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have an image with a label that comes over it, but when I save photo to album, of course the label doesn't show up.  How would I do this, I have search a lot, and nothing works.

Answer (score 5):

I did a bit of research in other questions to come up with an answer for you ([click here for the best and most detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137429/981049)), but the short answer for you would be this:

If you do combine your label and image into one `UIView` object (let's call it `myView`), you can do something like this: something like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.bounds.size);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

And the `viewImage` `UIImage` object would be what you save to the album.

Comment: Yup agreed. Create a new image for your particular screen frame.

Comment: I added a complete example for combining a label with an image for a toolbar button at the above link  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7137429/981049