# image merging, image scaling, touches,ImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiimageview

i have two images on my two ImageView. First image is a body image and second image is a tattoo image. By merging these two image i create a third image so its look like tattoo on body.

My question is :

1)It is possible to make third Image which looks real tattoo on the body ? And it is possible that user can use tattoo image from internet source or take from camera ?

2)Till now I only merge the body image and tattoo image. But tattoo image complete overlap the background image, my tattoo image size is small so i wants its show in middle of body image.

i can't upload image because my points less then 10 :(

my code is

```
-(void)mergeImage    

{    

int width=500;

int height=500;

UIImage *bottomImage = self.imageView.image;//background image

UIImage *image = self.imageViewTatoo.image;//foreground image

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

// Use existing opacity as is
[bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

// Apply supplied opacity if applicable
/
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.4];


UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

imageView.image=newImage;

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

}

Comment: Refer link [Merging Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137411/iphonesdk-merge-three-images-two-single-image?rq=1)  to know how u can merge images. Hope helpful.