# Cropping Bitmap Image like curv shape In Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I want to crop Image in  android.its possible in I-phone using Bezier curve,is there any way  to crop image or using Bezier curve in android.

[image: Curv Shape Image]

Comment: can't you create a shape(image) and do [Masking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614542/maskingcrop-image-in-frame)?

Comment: You want something like... first the image is Rectangle shape and then it becomes as above?