# Optimizing custom crop drawing

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, memory

I've implemented drawing for component like in picture following way:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int w = canvas.getWidth();
    int h = canvas.getHeight();

    if (mFinalBitmap == null) {
        mFinalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    if (mTempCanvas == null) {
        mTempCanvas = new Canvas(mFinalBitmap);
    }

    if (mBackgroundBitmap == null) {
        mBackgroundBitmap = createBitmap(R.drawable.rounded_background,
                w, h);
    }

    if (mBackgroundImage == null) {
        mBackgroundImage = createBitmap(R.drawable.image_for_background, w, h);
    }

    mTempCanvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    mTempCanvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundImage, 0, 0, mPaint);

    canvas.drawBitmap(mFinalBitmap, 0, 0, null);
}

private Bitmap createBitmap(int id, int width, int height) {

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext()
            .getResources(), id);

    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, false);
}
```

Where mPaint has

```
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
```

[image]

I'm wondering whether the code is good, or can be optimized for same result, it uses lot's of memory and is an potential trigger for `OutOfMemoryError`.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [Masking(crop) image in frame](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12614542/593709)

Comment: Code is almost the same there, lot's of bitmap creating, temporary Canvas where to draw, using ARGB_888 for result bitmap making it heavy. Is this really the very best solution to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following drawing can be achieved using `BitmapShader` with the image to be drawn, then I only need to create ALPHA_8 `Bitmap` to draw with `Paint` object using the shader. However shaders are pinned into window coordinates, so using this method inside scrolling components can cause some problems because the `Matrix` needs to be translated properly.

```
// Create bitmap shader
if (mShaderBitmap == null) {
    mShaderBitmap = use wanted bitmap here.
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(mShaderBitmap,
            TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
    mPaint.setShader(shader);
}

// Create alpha bitmap to draw with shader paint
if (mBitmapToDraw == null) {
    mBitmapToDraw = load the shape here with ALPHA_8 Config
}

canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapToDraw, 0, 0, mPaint);
```

Comment: how to "translate Matrix properly"?  I am using this method in custom drawable but it doesn't work on Android 4.0+, it's always pinned to the top left of the canvas (0,0) of the window, not my view!  But I have tested on 2.3.3 and it works fine!?!?