# Draw Square on exist bitmap image

Tags: android

I have a bitmap image and i want to draw a Square  over this image for special position , i researched but i could not found any solution , all solutions are for create Square on empty view , please advise a i am beginner

```
public class DrawView extends View
{
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {


        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        canvas.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100, myPaint);


    }

}
```

should i convert my bit map image to convas?how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628797/draw-rectangle-over-imageview may be helps this

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It does what you want and some more:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);            
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawRect(33, 60, 77, 77, paint );
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawRect(33, 33, 77, 60, paint );

    } 

}
```

To draw it:
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;

```
public class StartDraw extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(drawView);

    } 
}
```

Source: [Android canvas draw rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344497/android-canvas-draw-rectangle)