# How to draw a rectangle with black border and background transparent on Imageview?

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, draw, paint

I would like to draw a rectangle on an ImageView as a picture below (black border and transparent as background).
Basically I download an Image, put in in a ImageView and after I receive 4 points to draw a rectangle.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19629671/4494555).You can override onDraw() method in your class.

Comment: @Jas I've created the class, but get some error when i try to  include DrawView instead of my current ImageView

Comment: @alfo888_ibg if you got some error you need to fix it in some way

Comment: @pskink I get this error:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line: Error inflating class it.path.DrawView.

Comment: @alfo888_ibg i have no green idea what line 25 is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem for *android.view.InflateException* can be solved by deleting the constructors from DrawView class and auto generate them again. Now for the rectangle you have to have the onDraw similar like this:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    float leftx = 50;
    float topy =  50;
    float rightx =  150;
    float bottomy =  150;
    // FILL
    canvas.drawRect(leftx, topy, rightx, bottomy, paint);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    // BORDER
    canvas.drawRect(leftx, topy, rightx, bottomy, paint);
}
```

If  you want to get the coordinates on click an then draw the rectangle override the *onTouchEvent* method and do something like this

```
class DrawView extends ImageView {

    float x, y;
    float width = 60.0f;
    float height = 50.0f;
    boolean touched = false;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        if (touched) {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            // FILL
            canvas.drawRect(x, y, (x + width) / 0.5f, (y + height) / 0.5f, paint);

            paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            // BORDER
            canvas.drawRect(x, y, (x + width) / 0.5f, (y + height) / 0.5f, paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        touched = true;
        //getting the touched x and y position
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: yes it's true. I don't know why I didn't think about! last question. my image doesn't have the rectangle before, i have to draw the rectangles when i get the coordinates x y. how to make the coordinates dynamic and redraw the image with the rectangles?

Comment: ok then you have to override the _onTouchEvent_ method and  get x and y.

Comment: No,basically i have the coordinates (I recive it from a Json in my MainActivity). I need, gotten the coordinates, add rectangles to  previous imageview.

Comment: Hmm, then you have to make two Lists on the class, one for x-coordinates and one for y-coordinates and fill them with the values from json. Then on the _onDraw_ method make a for loop and replace x and y with the values from the lists.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help! :)

Comment: I added a full response to help another guys! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem in thanks the help of @vasilis.

I created:

```
class DrawView extends ImageView {
   private int numberOfRectangles=0;
   private ArrayList<Rectangles> listRect;
   public DrawView(Context context) {
       super(context);
   }
   public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
   }
   public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
   }

   @Override
   public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (numberOfRectangles> 0 && listRect!= null)
    {
        for (int i=0; i< numberOfRectangles; i++)
        {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            float leftx = listRect.get(i).getLeftx();
            float topy = listRect.get(i).getTopy();
            float rightx = listRect.get(i).getRightx();
            float bottomy = listRect.get(i).getBottomy();
            // FILL
            canvas.drawRect(leftx, topy, rightx, bottomy, paint);

            paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            // BORDER
            canvas.drawRect(leftx, topy, rightx, bottomy, paint);
        }
    }
}
 public void creatRectangles(ArrayList<Rectangles> arrayRettangoliTest) {
    numberOfRectangles=arrayRettangoliTest.size();
    this.listRect= arrayRettangoliTest;
    this.invalidate();
  }
```

}

in my xml file:

```
 <it.path.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
```

I create a Class Rectangles:

```
public class Rectangles {
   private float leftx;
   private float topy ;
   private float rightx;
   private float bottomy;

    public Rectangles(float leftx, float topy, float rightx, float bottomy)      {
        this.leftx = leftx;
        this.topy = topy;
        this.rightx = rightx;
        this.bottomy = bottomy;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Rectangles{" +
            "leftx=" + leftx +
            ", topy=" + topy +
            ", rightx=" + rightx +
            ", bottomy=" + bottomy +
            '}';
    }

    public void setLeftx(float leftx) {
        this.leftx = leftx;
    }

    public void setTopy(float topy) {
        this.topy = topy;
    }

    public void setRightx(float rightx) {
        this.rightx = rightx;
    }

    public void setBottomy(float bottomy) {
        this.bottomy = bottomy;
    }

    public float getLeftx() {
        return leftx;
    }

    public float getTopy() {
        return topy;
    }

    public float getRightx() {
       return rightx;
    }

    public float getBottomy() {
        return bottomy;
   }

}
```

And in my MainActivity (ex after an onClick()):

```
  ...
  ArrayList<Rectangles> arrayRectanglesTest= new ArrayList<>(4);
  arrayRectanglesTest.add(new Rectangles(50, 50, 100, 100));
  arrayRectanglesTest.add(new Rectangles(150, 150, 200, 200));
  arrayRectanglesTest.add(new Rectangles(250, 250, 300, 300));
  arrayRectanglesTest.add(new Rectangles(350, 350, 400, 400));
  arrayRectanglesTest.add(new Rectangles(450, 450, 500, 500));
  imageView.creatRectangles(arrayRectanglesTest);
  ...
```

So I made dynamic the number of rectangles
here the Result

[image]

Comment: x, y position is ok, but the rectangle size is not changed.
I want to know how to draw the rectangle starts with x, y position and I have the rectangle width and height.