# Image view Mask animation in android

Tags: android

i wanna do the mask animation to the ImageView the below image shows my requirement [image]

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614542/maskingcrop-image-in-frame/12637039#12637039)

Comment: @maddy thanks for your response  i already tried this here i am going to capture the image via camera and i converted the image as normal and gray scale image after that i placed the gray scale image over the normal image and i wanna do the above animation to hide the gray scale image and show hte original image

Comment: ok. I didn't no about that, that much I can do because I don't no much about `ImageMasking` and I am curious about how it can be done. I have vote-Up for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
I made a framelayout that supports masking.
The mask is a drawable but it can also be an animationDrawable.
Shameless selfplug

```
<com.christophesmet.android.views.maskableframelayout.MaskableFrameLayout
android:id="@+id/frm_mask_animated"
android:layout_width="100dp"
app:porterduffxfermode="DST_IN"
app:mask="@drawable/animation_mask"
android:layout_height="100dp">

<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:src="@drawable/unicorn"/>
```

You can find it [here](https://github.com/christophesmet/android_maskable_layout)