# Create image mask in android with 9png

Tags: android, imageview, android-canvas, mask

So I have this 9png :
[image]

And I have this image :
[image]

I need to achieve something like this:
[image]

This is the closest I can get to it:
[image]

This is how I tried to do it:

```
public class CustomView extends ImageView {

private Bitmap mImage;
private Bitmap mMask;
private int mPosX = 0;
private int mPosY = 0;

private final Paint maskPaint;
private final Paint imagePaint;

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    maskPaint = new Paint();
    maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

    imagePaint = new Paint();
    imagePaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER));

    mImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.dummy_video);
    mMask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.friend_bubble);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.drawBitmap(mMask, 0, 0, maskPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mImage, mPosX, mPosY, imagePaint);
    canvas.restore();
}

}
```

My guess is that the 9png just keeps on drawing and doesn't know when to stop.

Can anyone help? :)

Comment: No, the 9 patch only stretches in a View, not in a Bitmap object itself. Then you have to first make it scale into some View (possibly hidden), then take the scaled version and use that one as a mask.

Comment: This will help you to clip images with custom shapes [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614542/maskingcrop-image-in-frame)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein thanks for the tip. it works like that. I'm just not sure whether this is very optimized in a listview. There will be a lot of images

Comment: @AyyappanN for some reason the right side of my image does not have rounded corners, and it scales the whole image to the original height of the 9png. anyway I think I'll go with frank's method