# Diagonal line like Yahoo Digest app

Tags: android, android-layout

Can't find a way (even where to start with it) how to make diagonal view like in Yahoo Digest app:
[image]

Anyone? Seem to be quite popular, but don't know on what phrase should I look it for.

Comment: as stated in answer by @Gabe you can try diagonal mask. reference : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12637039/1602333

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  You overlap the image and the views below it, then have the image view either have the diagonal built into the image, or you mask the image before putting it into the image view.