# How to give Slope to ImageView in Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I am trying to give some slope in `ImageView`. Is it possible to do? If so then how?

Below image display exactly what i want to do. I have highlighted slope in `ImageView`.

[image]

Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve can be done in a couple of ways.

**First method - use an overlay image**

This is probably the most straight-forward method to implement this. Create a bitmap, or a drawable which is essentially a triangle with the desired background color (dark red in your example), and give it to an `ImageView` which is placed over your original `ImageView`, aligned to the bottom. This new `ImageView` will basically block out the bottom part of your original `ImageView`, giving you the desired effect.

**Second method - use image masks**

This method is slightly more complex, but will remove the need for having an additional `ImageView` in the layout. Basically, it means you'll need to process the bitmap a bit before setting it on the `ImageView`, and you'll need an additional bitmap which defines the shape of the resulting image. This bitmap will be the "mask" of your image. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614542/maskingcrop-image-in-frame) to see an example on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's working fine !!! but one remark is that we need to create mask image. We can't use normal image as a mask image.

Comment: You can mask your image from below link : http://www166.lunapic.com/editor/?action=mask

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with API > 11

```
mImageView.setRotation(angle);
```

with API>=11

You can also set it from xml

```
android:rotation="90"
```

Comment: android:rotation="90"  is just rotate ImageView. Not any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend ImageView and override onDraw method like this:

```
Paint paint=new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
@Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);            
            Path p=new Path();
            //start from bottom left corner
            p.moveTo(0,canvas.getHeight());
            //move to the offset
            p.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(),YOUR_OFFSET);
            //move to bottom right corner
            p.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight());
            //return to bottom left corner
            p.lineTo(0,canvas.getHeight());
            //clsoe the path
            p.close();
            canvas.drawPath(p,paint);
        }
```

that in case you want to paint the region with some color.

otherwise, you can define the clipped region and use [canvas.clipPath(Path path)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipPath(android.graphics.Path)) method