# Shape image like bubble with arrow (Android)

Tags: android, android-imageview, shapes

What I wanted is to turn my imageview to shape like this

I was using this library

https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview

[image]

I was able to add a border radius on it but my problem is 
I don't know how to add an arrow while adding border radius on it

Comment: Suggest you check [Masking(crop) image in frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614542/maskingcrop-image-in-frame).

Answer (score 1):

use this `app:siArrowPosition="right"`:-> **siArrowPosition where to point the arrow, currently left|right**

use this `app:siRadius="6dp"` :-> **corner radius in dp**
 **and**
        `app:siBorderWidth="6dp"`  **border width in dpfor border**

```
<com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.BubbleImageView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:src="@drawable/neo"
  app:siRadius="6dp"
  app:siBorderWidth="6dp"
  app:siArrowPosition="right"
  app:siSquare="true"/>
```

Comment: how about adding border radius on it? I mean where's the border readius on it too? you added the arrow

Answer (score 0):

check it to get this kind of bubble view https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView

```
<com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.BubbleView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:shape_bubble_arrowHeight="10dp"
    app:shape_bubble_arrowWidth="10dp"
    app:shape_bubble_arrowPosition="bottom"
    app:shape_bubble_borderRadius="20dp"
    app:arrow_posititon_percent="0.5"
    >

     <!-- YOUR CONTENT -->

</com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.BubbleView>
```

[image]