# Clip an image with respect to a lower image's dimensions

Tags: java, android, android-image

There are 2 images in my app. I want to clip the upper image with respect to the lower image's dimensions:

[image]

I tried for the `ClipDrawable` from android developers docs but somehow got confused.

Comment: Apply transparent background in image root view

Comment: This is related to Image Masking. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614542/maskingcrop-image-in-frame?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thanks for the references... But still stuck...

Comment: see [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Xfermodes.java)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot that reference @VirRajpurohit... It's working as i wanted... and thanks to others as well

Comment: Any idea if I could move the content image under the mask and clip it dynamically through a button?