# How to get mutable bitmap using ImageDecoder?

Tags: android, bitmap, imagedecoder

I am creating bitmap as follows

```
       ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.getContentResolver(), mSourceUri);
        try {
            bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This returns immutable bitmap. I saw [google documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder.html#setMutableRequired(boolean)) and there is a method `setMutableRequired()` but I couldn't find how to use this method. It doesn't work on ImageDecoder as well as source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit prettier solution

```
imageBitmap = imageBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59785944/9640177)

Comment: There's nothing pretty about this solution - it makes a copy of a bitmap, doubling the memory required for a moment. setMutableRequired is a proper way without extra copy

Comment: @Dimezis and how you can get it from video memory without copyng?

Comment: @Alexufo with `setMutableRequired` the returned bitmap will be software-allocated https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder#ALLOCATOR_DEFAULT

Answer (score 4):

Provide an `ImageDecoder.OnHeaderDecodedListener` as the second parameter to `ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap()`.

Inside the listener you get the `ImageDecoder`, to which you can make desired changes.

```java
ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(imageSource, (decoder, info, source) -> {
    decoder.setMutableRequired(true);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**From API 28**

```
ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            ImageDecoder.OnHeaderDecodedListener listener = new ImageDecoder.OnHeaderDecodedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onHeaderDecoded(@NonNull ImageDecoder decoder, @NonNull ImageDecoder.ImageInfo info, @NonNull ImageDecoder.Source source) {
                    decoder.setMutableRequired(true);
                }
            };
            bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source, listener);
```

Comment: Create a listener just to decode a bitmap. That's nuts.

Comment: @Humpity why? bitmap in video memory, how you can get access to it in other case?

Answer (score 0):

Till the time a proper answer arrives to this question. Anyone with similar difficulty as mine can use BitmapFactory method to get mutable bitmap

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inMutable = true;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(mSourceUri), null, options);
```

inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7698162/9640177).