# Android Hexagon ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, mask

how can I achieve the hexagon imageview that is shown below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxYZ5.jpg

Note that I tried the solution which is at this question:
[How to give hexagon shape to ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601400/how-to-give-hexagon-shape-to-imageview)

And I also tried this solution:
[Masking(crop) image in frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614542/maskingcrop-image-in-frame)

But I don't want to fill a color outside of the hexagon. I want it to be transparent, so the views and images behind can be seen.

By the way I tried, BitmapShader, PorterDuffXFermode etc. but cannot managed to get the result I wanted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I at last solved my problem. I find a very useful library that specifically does the trick I wanted. It is masking the imageview with a svg type vector image.

Library:

[CustomShapeImageView](https://github.com/MostafaGazar/CustomShapeImageView)

Result:

[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s4eqg46tfwj3hwb/Screenshot%202014-10-02%2001.19.58.png?dl=0)

**Edit:** I also want to share the hexagonal svg with you, in case of necessity.

```
<svg width="205" height="237" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<title>hexagon</title>
<metadata id="metadata3064">image/svg+xml</metadata>
<g>
<title>Layer 1</title>
<polygon points="0,59.27092742919922 0,177.8127899169922 102.66026306152344,237.08370971679688 205.3205108642578,177.8127899169922 205.3205108642578,59.27092742919922 102.66026306152344,0 " id="svg_1" fill="#000000"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi. SafaOrhan, The svg has to be saved in which folder and which extension?

Comment: @Jack You can put it into /res/raw folder without any extension.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is my code for this, this supports shadows to:**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class HexagonImageView extends ImageView {

    private Path hexagonPath;
    private Path hexagonBorderPath;
    private float radius;
    private Bitmap image;
    private int viewWidth;
    private int viewHeight;
    private Paint paint;
    private BitmapShader shader;
    private Paint paintBorder;
    private int borderWidth = 4;

    public HexagonImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setup();
    }

    public HexagonImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup();
    }

    public HexagonImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        paintBorder = new Paint();
        setBorderColor(Color.WHITE);
        paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
        this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
        paintBorder.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Color.BLACK);

        hexagonPath = new Path();
        hexagonBorderPath = new Path();
    }

    public void setRadius(float r) {
        this.radius = r;
        calculatePath();
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth)  {
        this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int borderColor)  {
        if (paintBorder != null)
            paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);

        this.invalidate();
    }

    private void calculatePath() {

        float triangleHeight = (float) (Math.sqrt(3) * radius / 2);
        float centerX = viewWidth/2;
        float centerY = viewHeight/2;

        hexagonBorderPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radius);
        hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleHeight, centerY + radius/2);
        hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleHeight, centerY - radius/2);
        hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX, centerY - radius);
        hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleHeight, centerY - radius/2);
        hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleHeight, centerY + radius/2);
        hexagonBorderPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radius);

        float radiusBorder = radius - borderWidth;    
        float triangleBorderHeight = (float) (Math.sqrt(3) * radiusBorder / 2);

        hexagonPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radiusBorder);
        hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleBorderHeight, centerY + radiusBorder/2);
        hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleBorderHeight, centerY - radiusBorder/2);
        hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX, centerY - radiusBorder);
        hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleBorderHeight, centerY - radiusBorder/2);
        hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleBorderHeight, centerY + radiusBorder/2);
        hexagonPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radiusBorder);

        invalidate();
    }

    private void loadBitmap()  {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) this.getDrawable();

        if (bitmapDrawable != null)
            image = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        loadBitmap();

        // init shader
        if (image != null) {

            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

            shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), false), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            paint.setShader(shader);

            canvas.drawPath(hexagonBorderPath, paintBorder);
            canvas.drawPath(hexagonPath, paint);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

        viewWidth = width - (borderWidth * 2);
        viewHeight = height - (borderWidth * 2);

        radius = height / 2 - borderWidth;

        calculatePath();

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private int measureWidth(int measureSpec)   {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)  {
            result = specSize;
        }
        else {
            result = viewWidth;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight, int measureSpecWidth)  {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            result = specSize;
        }
        else {
            result = viewHeight;
        }

        return (result + 2);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've read this and looks valid. They even have a video tutorial: http://www.41post.com/4794/programming/android-rendering-a-path-with-a-bitmap-fill on how to fill a shape with a texture

Comment: I don't want to fill with a color. I want to mask it so the views those behind it, can be seen.

Comment: Using their tut you can create a transparent image with a textured shape.