# How to create round curved rectangle in android?

Tags: android

I need to create the this kind of design.Help me.

[image]

Helps will be appreciated.

Comment: OP wants rounded corner + curved edges

Comment: @pgiitu see the question carefully and answer ,or tell me it is possible dublicate..lol

Comment: yes ketan ahir. answer is heartly welcome.

Comment: I suggest you to use image instead of creating shape.

Comment: i dont want that. because maintaining the images by resolution is very big job. i need code only. i think coding only will be comfortable.

Comment: @Hassan you can create a 9-patch image.

Comment: yes .i planned already and created.thanks for the help

Comment: @Hassan Just an idea, you can create a hexagon and change the height and curves of it. see this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/22601400/1979347

Comment: @RohanKandwal yes dude. i will try. thank you for the help

Answer (score -1):

create a xml file in drawable folder, and set this drawable file as your view's background. it will help you...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ff25183d" />

    <!-- <stroke android:width="1dp"
         android:color="#ff666666"
         />-->

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:topRightRadius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: i need not only round cornered.rounded from all side.. Read the question carefully and place the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Create file in your Drawable folder

**file name : round_corner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

And Apply background in xml file like this :

```
android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
```

Comment: Why the guys not listening the question before answering.. i need not only round cornered yar. even bent in side by side also. see the images carefully. and answer.

Answer (score -1):

this is working for me just checked it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="105dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
  />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000" />
    <padding
        android:left="15dp"
        android:top="15dp"
        android:right="15dp"
        android:bottom="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: you can adjust the gradient angle and radius as per your requirement.

Comment: gradient is for color dude. how can it change the shape?