# How to create Hexagon shape in .xml format

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create Hexagon shape for my project so I want to create that shape in .xml format so how can i create.

[image: like this image]

[image: like this image]

Comment: Want you to use in `Image View` background ? or any other purpose.

Comment: yes, I want to use in ImageView background. so I want this shape in .xml format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22987264/1992254

Comment: I want in .xml format guys.  use for ImageView background

Comment: you can create your own hexagonal shape...check my [tutorial](https://github.com/mohit008/Android-Geomatry-Figure/blob/master/res/drawable/hexagon.xml)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best solution for you would be use VectorDrawable:

Hexagon shape as vector drawable:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="628.0"
android:viewportWidth="726.0" android:width="27dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#00ffffff"
    android:pathData="m723,314c-60,103.9 -120,207.8 -180,311.8 -120,0 -240,0 -360,0C123,521.8 63,417.9 3,314 63,210.1 123,106.2 183,2.2c120,0 240,0 360,0C603,106.2 663,210.1 723,314Z"
    android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="4"/>
</vector>
```

Update(28:07.2016):

To support API below Lollipop use support library http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html remember to use VectorDrawableCompat instead VectorDrawable

Comment: There was something wrong with stackoverflow formatting and </vector> tag was cut. I fixed it.

Comment: yes it's working. can you share which tool you use. to making this format

Comment: Click right mouse button to drawable folder -> New -> Vector Asset -> Local SVG File -> Next. I used Inkscape to generate svg, but you could download from web too.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is supported starting with API 21 (Android 5)

Comment: Nope, it is supported for earlier versions by support library - more details: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Comment: how to create portrait hexagon

Answer (score 3):

[if you want output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ukzI.png)
if you want full hexagon

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="512dp"
android:height="512dp"
android:viewportWidth="512"
android:viewportHeight="512">

<path
    android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:pathData="m485.291,129.408 l-224,-128c-3.285,-1.877 -7.296,-1.877 
-10.581,0l-224,128c-3.328,1.899 -5.376,5.44 -5.376,9.259v234.667c0,3.819 2.048,7.36 
5.376,9.259l224,128c1.643,0.939 3.456,1.408 5.291,1.408s3.648,-0.469 
5.291,-1.408l224,-128c3.328,-1.899 5.376,-5.44 5.376,-9.259v-234.667c-0.001,-3.819 
-2.049,-7.36 -5.377,-9.259z" />

</vector>
```

Answer (score 1):

While most solutions would involve including the **[ShapeImageView](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview)** (which is a great library, btw), you can always write your own logic to create a custom hexagon shaped layout.

All you need to do is define the properties of the **`Path`** object and then use that in the onDraw() method of the layout using the Canvas.

This is how you would create the hexagon path.

```
  float midx = getWidth() / 2;
  float midy = getHeight() / 2;

  Path p = new Path();

  p.moveTo(midx, midy);
  p.lineTo(midx+150, midy + 220);
  p.lineTo(midx, midy + 220);
  p.lineTo(midx-150, midy + 220);
  p.lineTo(midx-300, midy);
  p.lineTo(midx-150, midy-220);
  p.lineTo(midx+150, midy-220);
  p.lineTo(midx+300, midy);
  p.lineTo(midx+150, midy + 220);
  return p;
```

Now, in your custom hexagon layout, use this path in onDraw().

```
@Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      Path clipPath = new Path();
      clipPath.addPath(p); //p is the path you created above
      canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
      canvas.drawColor(Color.RED); //optional

      super.onDraw(canvas)
}
```

Once you have your custom layout ready, you can set the background of the layout to any drawable you want (just as you would do for any other layouts).

Comment: This is incredibly useful information. For the image creator I wanted to make.

Comment: Glad to be of help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use VectorDrawable (VectorDrawableCompat for old version) https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html. You can easialy import shape from .svg files.