# How to impliment hexagon shapes interface in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hey how could I impliment hexagon shapes interface in android for more reference please check this image:

[image]

this image is screenshot from [APUS Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apusapps.launcher)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this  [Android Shape ImageView](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview)  library or check this [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37297103/6059438)