# Hexagon Image View in NS

Tags: android, image, nativescript

How can i create a component like this is NS?

[How to give hexagon shape to ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601400/how-to-give-hexagon-shape-to-imageview#answer-26701037)

I want to create a image component that has a hexagon look, but i cant figure it out how to extend nativescript classes correctly in order to obtain this result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a perfect case for `clip-path`, which is a CSS property that NativeScript supports out of the box!

View:

```
  <ContentView width="150" height="150" class="someimage hexagon"></ContentView>
```

CSS:

```
.someimage {
  background-image: url("~/assets/images/myimage.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hexagon {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}
```

Or you can apply it directly to an image, like in this example:

```
<Image src="~/assets/images/myimage.jpg" class="hexagon"></Image>
```

You can tweak the appearance of the hexagon with this amazing tool: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Applying it to the `Image` is preferred because Android has very poor way of handling Images in the memory and if your intent to use this hexagon image for a lot of images you will see find yourself with OOM exceptions. The `Image` is optimized in {N} for those cases.